# How to make the human marker move on the map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I have a marker humanMarker on the map. How to make it move when the user is moving?

```
private Marker humanMarker;

humanMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.human)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the `onLocationChanged` method. `humanMarker` will move when the location of the user is changed.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Update current location of the marker
    humanMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
}
```